# Matlab genetic algorithms in portfolio management

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm, portfolio

I would like to try genetic algorithms in portfolio management, but I don't now how the main function and constrains should look like.

I have matrix with stock prices, vector with weights and script that calculates portfolio price and portfolio return/risk(std) ratio. I want to use genetic algorithm in MATLAB so different combinations of wrights could be tested and optimal portfolio could be found (optimal - highest return/risk(std) ratio.

`prices` - matrix where columns represents different stocks and rows represents day prices.

`w` - vector with weights `[0.333, 0.333, 0.333]`

script that calculates portfolio performance:

```
d = length(prices);    
n = numel(prices);

for j = 1:d
    temp = 0;
    for i = 1:n
        temp = temp + prices(j,i) * w(i);
    end
    ap(j) = temp;
end

port_performance = rr_ratio(ap); %calculates return/risk(std) ratio.
```

I need to find best combination of weights, so `port_performance` would have maximum value. How GA function should look like, so `sum(w) = 1;` and each element of `w >= 0`?

Thank you

Comment: You could save yourself some lines of code and just write `ap = prices * w'`

Answer (score 1):

This is an extremely open ended question. There is no one perfect way to apply genetic algorithms to portfolio optimization. Generally, what you would do is something like the following:

1. Generate a large number of candidate portfolios at random, that satisfy your constraints.
2. Evaluate each portfolio according to your "fitness metric" which is presumably the risk/reward ratio.
3. Choose a subset of your portfolios to "reproduce" and kill the rest. Generally you do something like choosing the top 50% by performance.
4. "Breed" some new portfolios. You can do this by asexual reproduction (i.e. clone your old portfolios) or sexual reproduction (pick the old portfolios in pairs and combine them somehow to generate a new portfolio).
5. Introduce mutations into the portfolios with some small mutation rate (say p = 0.01). For example, you could randomly move some of the weights up/down, or randomly swap the weights for a couple of different stocks.
6. You now have a new population of portfolios, and you can start again.

To generate your random portfolios to begin with so that each `w(i) >= 0` and `sum(w) = 1` you could just do

```
>> w = rand(numPortfolios, numStocks);
>> w = bsxfun(@rdivide, w, sum(w,2));
```

Now each row of `w` is a candidate set of portfolio weights.

To breed two portfolios you could just take the average

```
>> wNew = 0.5 * (w1 + w2);
```

Or you could select elements at random from each portfolio and then renormalize to ensure that the weights sum to 1.

```
>> wNew = zeros(1, numStocks);
>> x = rand(1, numStocks) < 0.5;
>> wNew( x) = w1(x);
>> wNew(~x) = w2(x);
>> wNew = wNew / sum(wNew);
```

You might also consider taking a look at [this paper](http://www.er.ethz.ch/publications/RoudierMScThesis.pdf).